# Are Tensor sharding and Tensor tilting the same implementation?

Tags: compiler-optimization, tensor, tensorflow-xla

I know the each concept of Tensor Sharding and Tensor Tiling.
But Is there any differences between them?
Especially about the XLA/Hlo or GSPMD concept in parallel training (data parallel or model parallel).

Comment: Stack Overflow's [tag:xla] tag is about ancient MS Excel addons.  I assume you intend a different meaning, presumably https://www.tensorflow.org/xla .  IDK if there's a tag for it on Stack Overflow; would [tensorflow] apply here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Tensor sharding and Tensor tilting are not the same implementation. They are both techniques used in parallel training of machine learning models, but they serve different purposes.

Tensor sharding is a technique used to distribute the computation of large tensors across multiple devices or machines in a distributed system. The tensor is divided into smaller pieces, or shards, and each shard is processed independently on different devices.

Tensor tilting, on the other hand, is a technique used to optimize the performance of tensor operations by partitioning the tensor into smaller, fixed-size tiles that can be loaded into memory and processed more efficiently.

Both techniques can be used in conjunction with XLA (Accelerated Linear Algebra) and Hlo (High-Level Optimizer) technologies to optimize the computation graph used in deep learning training. GSPMD (gated synchronous parallelism data parallelism) is a specific parallel training approach that leverages these technologies and techniques to efficiently distribute the data and computations required for training across multiple devices or machines.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Still, I cannot understand the differences. As far as I understand, In XLA/HLO implementation especially in the class HLOSharding, sharding is done in the HLO module and it eventually uses tensor tiling scheme. So, I confused that is there any differences between them.

Comment: it uses tensor tiling scheme to optimize the performance of parallel processing